# STRING type or SSTRING element for a text field in table? Pros and cons

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I need to create a Z table to store reasons for modifications of a certain custom object.

In the UI, the user will pick a reason ID and then optionally fill a text box. The table will have more or less the fields below:

```
key objectID
key changeReasonID
    changedOn
    changedBy
    comments
```

My doubt is with the comments field. I read the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abenddic_character_byte_types.htm) about the limitations of STRING and SSTRING, but it's not clear to me if a STRING type field used in a transparent table has a limited length or not.

Even if the length is not limited (at least by the DB), I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use this approach or would you recommend CHAR/SSTRING types with a fix length instead?

**My system is running MSSQL database.

Comment: STRING and RAWSTRING have an "unlimited" length (probably something like 2GB and limited by database space available of course - maybe it could be more but ABAP limit is 2GB anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings have unlimited length, both in ABAP structures/tables, and in the database.

Most databases will store only a pointer in this column that points to the real CLOB value which is stored in a different memory segment. As a result, they restrict the usage of these columns, and may not allow you to use them as a key or index.

If I remember correctly, ABAP supports [a maximum of 16 string fields](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1354957/E) per structure, which naturally limits its use cases. Also consider that ABAP structures have a maximum size.

For your case, if the comment will remain the only long field, and if you are actually fine with storing unlimited input (--> security constraints?), string sounds like a reasonable option.

If you are unsure what the future will bring, or to be on the safe side regarding security, you might want to opt for sstring or simply a long char instead.

Comment: A DDIC table may have a maximum of 16 columns since 7.02 (just checked for 7.52, it's still 16), and it was 3 in 7.0. Source: [note 1354957 - Tables with more than 3 long string fields](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1354957/E).

Comment: Thanks, the technical part is clear, I guess the performance is also impacted but this table won't be accessed very often. However, I'm not sure what to decide about the security aspect, is it a general recommendation to never use unlimited STRINGs for database fields? Is there a way to be safe other than just establish a maximum length?

Comment: Length limitation is a standard procedure for securing things. The less characters you offer, the harder it is to exploit security vulnerabilities, as the attcker's code is also limited. You cannot rely on that alone, of course, and should blacklist/whitelist check and sanitize/escape/encode all input. Also keep regular non-functional requirements in mind. Imagine some user misuses this and pastes hundreds of pages of text in each comment. This might fill up your database much quicker than expected. Reasonable length limits may prevent this.

Comment: @Sandra, thanks for the clarification. I remembered this issue from a long time ago and never rechecked in "recent" times.

Comment: As usual right on the money Florian. One aspect you could add to your excellent answer for future google searchs, is the limitations on indexing and therefore on search when strings are used. The max char 1333 for pseudo strings when index and a search may be required.